# HOWTO access microphone data

Tags: 14.04, microphone

I need to access my microphone data in 3 ways, how do I:

1. dump the raw data stream generated by microphone into terminal
2. play/listen to the real-time audio captured, using the gui or terminal.
3. record the audio into wave files using the terminal.

Also if possible I would like to be able to do number 1 and 3 at the same time.

Thank you for your time.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Mic: Logitech G930

Answer (score 3):

You need to work with **Audio Linux Sound Architecture - ALSA** . The main How-To is found [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page).

With above How-To you can:

1. get List of sound devices and select one which has IRQ.
2. record sound into `.wav` with `arecord -d 10 /tmp/test-mic.wav`
3. and play that file with `aplay /tmp/test-mic.wav`.

But if you need to dump raw data stream and work with that you should go deeper and refer to [AlsaProject](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page). You'll find several good links on how to do that. For example [ALSA Programming HOWTO](http://users.suse.com/~mana/alsa090_howto.html).